# SSRS graph rendering wrong in IE (yet correct in Chrome or Firefox)

Tags: internet-explorer, sharepoint, reporting-services

I just became aware of a bug or rendering problem when viewing SSRS-reports in a sharepoint web-part.

Chrome or firefox are usually the browsers of choice, so didn't notice this behaviour. Having a DataBar rendering correct in Chrome and Firefox, but not in IE.

I tried to emulate in different IE but no difference.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to fix this problem?

IE having weird sizes of the bar (compared to the value)

[image: IE rendering the bars in wrong size]

Chrome and Firefox rendering correctly.

[image: Chrome and Firefox rendering the same report correct in size]

Comment: is this on IE11? might be this https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/810527/sql-server-reporting-services-is-not-compatible-with-internet-explorer-11

Comment: I'll try to find a way to test on lower versions than IE11, but the mentioned big seems to be the tool-bar for export? Not sure if it also affects the rendering of graphs?

Comment: on IE you can F12 and lower the version on the emulator

Comment: I tried that already, as mentioned in the post, but unfortunately without any difference.

Comment: I saw this part "
In this scenario, ASP.NET cannot recognize Internet Explorer 11 and will not render the content correctly. After the user applies this hotfix, Internet Explorer 11 can be recognized as InternetExplorer by ASP.NET."

Comment: I'll have to investigate what versions and OS is running on the servers.